# USing IF..Then..Else with select queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have 3 tables like this :

`comment` table :

```
commentId pid    sid       text      vid
1          1     null    comment 1    1
2         null    1     comment 2    1
3          2     null    comment 3    1
```

`student` table:

```
sid     firstname   lastname
1         john       adam
2         joan       adam
```

`professor` table :

```
pid    firstname   lastname
1       mark        abram
2       sean        hoak
```

I want to write a query so the result to return like this :

```
firstname    lastname
mark          abram
john          adam
sean          hoak
```

m

```
if (select query ==null) 
   then (select query 1) 
   else select (query 2)
```

I tried the following :

```
if((select pid from comment==null)
then select student.firstname , student.lastname from student where sid in (select sid from comment where vid=1)

else
(select professor.firstname ,professor.lastname from professor where pid in (select pid from comment where vid=1)
```

but with no luck.

Any ideas how to achieve the wanted result ?

Comment: Can we please have an "english" explanation of what it is you want to select?

Comment: == Null? do you mean IS NULL?

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question , you want to see the names of who posted comments with vid =1, regardless of whether they are student or professor.  This will do that.  A `LEFT JOIN` brings everything from the left table, including nulls.  Just `LEFT JOIN` to both on the appropriate id and you will get what you need.

```
SELECT ISNULL(p.firstname,s.firstname), ISNULL(p.lastname,s.lastname) --,comment or whatever other things you want to show
FROM Comment C
LEFT JOIN professor P ON P.pid = c.pid
LEFT JOIN student s ON s.sid = c.sid
WHERE vid = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't create the tables and test - overlooked at first - added.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly,, this query should do:

```
SELECT A.commentId, ISNULL(B.firstname,C.firstname) firstname, ISNULL(B.lastname,C.lastname) lastname
FROM comment A
LEFT JOIN student B
ON A.sid = B.sid
LEFT JOIN professor C
ON A.pid = C.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.firstname, s.firstname), COALESCE(p.lastname, s.lastname)
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN Professors p
ON c.pid = p.pid
LEFT JOIN Students s
ON c.sid = s.sid
```

Sort of nasty, and could probably be improved if you created a view that merged student and professor.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
select student.firstname , student.lastname 
from student 
where sid in (select sid from comment where vid=1 and pid is null)
UNION ALL
select professor.firstname ,professor.lastname 
from professor 
where pid in (select pid from comment where vid=1 and PID is not null)
```

Comment: it gets returned unique and unordered ( all students shown first then all professors